# Filtering a Word Doc with VBScripts

Tags: vbscript, automation, ms-word

I have a very large word doc that is about 100 pages and is automatically generated. The problem is most of the time I want to filter the options (only have certain sections and subsections). Heading 1 is the project, Heading 2 is a diagram, and Heading 3 are the components of a diagram. I have been trying to use VBScripts to pick which heading 2s and 3s I want, then delete all the content contained in whatever headings I do not want. I have been playing around with VBScripts and I cannot seem to be able to get a list of the headings. This is what my sub that should be pulling headings looks like.

```
Sub getHeadings()
    Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
    For Each p In objSelection.Paragraphs
        WScript.Echo p.Range.Text
    Next p
End Sub
```

The real problem I am having is finding good documentation for using VBScripts with Word. If anyone could help me out or point me in the direction of good documentation that would be great.

By the way. I can't do this in VBA because this Word doc is automatically generated by another program and I would like to be able to just do a quick command in the command line and have the doc ready to go instead on opening the doc, finding the macro, pasting it in and then running it. Eventually the goal is to combine this script with the script that generates the doc.

EDIT:
As requested, I am adding some of the script I have that I used to open up the doc

```
Dim objWord
Dim path
path = "C:\path\to\doc\test.docx"
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

openWordDoc(path)

Sub openWordDoc(filepath)
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(filepath)
    Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
end Sub
```

Comment: Word's Find functionality can search formatting (styles). That might be somethig to investigate...

Comment: What is `objWord`, can you show us how it is instantiated? There should be a line somewhere in your code `Set objWord = ...` or you will get an error on this line `Set objSelection = objWord.Selection` stating `Object variable or with block variable not set`. But as you haven't provided information about how it doesn't work, we can only assume which doesn't make for a good question. You're welcome to [edit] the question and provide some more information like, how does it not work? and adding a [mcve].

Comment: Using VBScript for Word automation essentially means that you're using VBA via the COM interface that Word exposes. The best approach is probably to write your code as VBA, then [translate that to VBScript](http://sdb.planetcobalt.net/vba2vbs.shtml).

Answer (score 2):

The following Word macro allows you to pick a heading level, then go through the document looking at all content spanned by headings at that level, choosing which to retain or delete. This is far more efficient than simply looping though all the paragraphs.

```
Sub ReviewHeadings()
Dim RngHd As Range, h As Long, Rslt
h = CLng(InputBox("Input the Heading level (e.g. 1) to process", "Heading Content Review", 1))
If (h < 1) Or (h > 9) Then Exit Sub
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .Style = "Heading " & h
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    Set RngHd = .Paragraphs(1).Range
    Set RngHd = RngHd.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\HeadingLevel")
    RngHd.Select
    Rslt = MsgBox("Retain this portion?", vbYesNoCancel)
    If Rslt = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
    If Rslt = vbNo Then RngHd.Delete
    .Start = RngHd.End
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Set RngHd = Nothing
End Sub
```

You could do something similar with a VBscript, replacing the named constants with their numeric equivalents.

Comment: There's a bit more to required to *"do something similar"* than just replacing the named constants, this code will trip up in VBScript for a few reasons you haven't stated.